# Changing a Char to another specified Char in a specified position structure

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, structure

I need to change a specified characters eg: a->z, d->b in a string. for eg: input is abandoned; output is zbznboneb. This is my code.

```
typedef struct {
    char source;
    char code;
} Rule;

void encodeChar (Rule table[5], char *s, char *t);

int main ()
{
    char s[80], t[80];
    Rule table[5] = { 'a', 'd', 'b', 'z', 'z', 'a', 'd', 'b', '\0', '\0'
    };

    printf ("Source string: \n");
    gets (s);
    encodeChar (table, s, t);
    printf ("Encoded string: %s\n", t);
    return 0;
}

void encodeChar (Rule table[5], char *s, char *t)
{
    int j = 0;

    while (s[j] != '\0') {
        if (s[j] == 'a')
            putchar ('d');
        if (s[j] == 'b')
            putchar ('z');
        if (s[j] == 'z')
            putchar ('a');
        j++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it gives me output dz, only and does not return the whole word when, i type abandoned.

Comment: Why do you think I get the feeling you're not reading a book?

Comment: I'll tell you why... 1/ this problem is so basic that people who *do* read books generally don't have it, 2/ it's the kind of question I see from people who *don't* read books more often than not, 3/ I see this kind of question dozens of times a day and 4/ **rather than asking such question one after another after another, you could save lots of time by reading a book**

Comment: If your book tells you to use `gets`, burn it now! Get a new book. `gets` has been removed from the C11 standard due to its insecurity, use `fgets` instead.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You know as well as I do, this person most likely *isn't using a book*... There's nothing to *burn*, though that doesn't change the fact that *it isn't working for him/her*. Look past the `gets` issue, and you'll see, this is a *very basic* problem people who read books won't possibly have. People who read books will ask about the book long before they try to write code like this... *if they need to*...

Comment: like [this](https://ideone.com/diaPYS)

Comment: Thank you so much. trying to understanding what u have coded. is it possible for u to write comment beside the code? @BLUEPIXY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to, and in agreement with, the other answer, there are fundamentals you are missing.

When you get into `encodeChar`, what parameter are you using to tell you how many elements `table` has? (you do want to iterate over each element in `table` checking `table[i].source` against each character to determine if a substitution is needed, right?)

**note:** C generally uses all *lowercase* for variable and function names while reserving all *uppercase* for constants and macros. C avoids the use of *camelCase* and *MixedCase* names -- leave those for C++ or java. While it is a matter of style, so it is largely up to you, it does say a lot about your appreciation for C, just like using `gets` does....

Don't use *magic numbers* in your code. If you need a constant, (e.g. `80`), declare one at the top of your code, e.g.

```
#define MAXC 80   /* maximum characters for input buffer */
```

If you have multiple constants to declare, using an `enum` is an orderly way to declare global constants.

Using constants prevents having to pick through multiple array declarations to change their size. There is one convenient place up top to make the change.

Don't use `gets`, it is helpless against buffer overrun and has been removed from C11. Use `fgets`. All valid *line-oriented* input functions (e.g. `fgets`, and POSIX `getline`) *read and include* the trailing `'\n'` in the buffers they fill with input. Therefore, you need to trim the trailing newline from input, or you will have `'\n'` dangling off the end of any string you store that can cause problems with comparisons, etc.. Simply get the length and check character `length - 1` to validate it is a `'\n'`, then just overwrite it with a *nul-terminating* character (`'\0'` or `0`, they are equivalent)

It's quite simple, e.g.:

```
len = strlen (s);                  /* get length of s   */
if (len && s[len - 1] == '\n')     /* check for \n      */
    s[--len] = 0;                  /* overwrite with \0 */
```

**note:** by using `--len` you now have the new length preserved in `len`.

Finally, for your `encodechar` function, you need to know how many elements of `table` you have. For each character in `s` you will compare it to each `table[i].source` if a match is found, then you will assign `table[i].code` to `t` and go to the next character. If not found, you will simply assign the character in `s` to `t`.

**note:** there is no need for the 5th element of `table` (e.g. `'\0'`, `'\0'`), you can easily *nul-terminate* `t` without it -- and it is not a replacement.

Putting that together, you could write `encodechar` similar to the following:

```
void encodechar (rule *table, size_t sz, char *s, char *t)
{
    size_t i;

    while (*s) {                            /* for each character */
        int replaced = 0;                   /* replaced flag */
        for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)            /* for each element of table */
            if (*s == table[i].source) {    /* is char == table[i].source */
                *t = table[i].code;         /* replace it */
                replaced = 1;               /* set replaced flag */
                break;                      /* get next character */
            }
        if (!replaced)                      /* if not replaced */
            *t = *s;                        /* copy from s to t */
        s++, t++;                           /* increment s and t */
    }
    *t = 0;                                 /* nul-terminate t */
}
```

Putting it altogether, and noting `main()` is type `int` and therefore returns a value (See: [**C11 Standard §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup (draft n1570)**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). See also: [**See What should main() return in C and C++?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)), you can do something similar to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 80   /* maximum characters for input buffer */

typedef struct {
    char source;
    char code;
} rule;

void encodechar (rule *table, size_t sz, char *s, char *t);

int main (void) {

    char s[MAXC] = "", t[MAXC] = "";
    rule table[] = { {'a', 'd'}, {'b', 'z'}, {'z', 'a'}, {'d', 'b'} };
    size_t len = 0, n = sizeof table/sizeof *table;

    printf ("Source string : ");
    if (!fgets (s, MAXC, stdin)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    len = strlen (s);                  /* get length of s   */
    if (len && s[len - 1] == '\n')     /* check for \n      */
        s[--len] = 0;                  /* overwrite with \0 */

    encodechar (table, n, s, t);

    printf ("Encoded string: %s\n", t);

    return 0;
}

void encodechar (rule *table, size_t sz, char *s, char *t)
{
    size_t i;

    while (*s) {                            /* for each character */
        int replaced = 0;                   /* replaced flag */
        for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)            /* for each element of table */
            if (*s == table[i].source) {    /* is char == table[i].source */
                *t = table[i].code;         /* replace it */
                replaced = 1;               /* set replaced flag */
                break;                      /* get next character */
            }
        if (!replaced)                      /* if not replaced */
            *t = *s;                        /* copy from s to t */
        s++, t++;                           /* increment s and t */
    }
    *t = 0;                                 /* nul-terminate t */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/encode
Source string : abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Encoded string: dzcbefghijklmnopqrstuvwxya
```

Always compile with *warnings enabled*, and **do not** accept code until it *compiles cleanly without warning*. To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra` to your `gcc` compile string. (add `-pedantic` for several additional warnings). For *VS* (`cl.exe` on windoze), add `/Wall`. For `clang`, add `-Weverything`. Read and understand each warning. They will identify any problems, and the exact line on which they occur. You can learn as much about coding by simply listening to what your compiler is telling you as you can from most tutorials.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: This clearly has helped me a lot. clear my doubts and provide sufficient explanation. I am new to C and i hope one day when ive mastered C language, i will be able to share my knowledge to new programmer as i understand their situation. Thank you so much for your time sir! @david

Comment: You will. Learning C is a journey, not a race, enjoy the ride.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd be so kind as to explain where you output any character *other than `a`, `z` or `d`* within this code:

```
void encodeChar(Rule table[5], char *s, char *t)
{
    int j =0;

    while(s[j] != '\0')
    {
        if (s[j] == 'a')
            putchar('d');
        if (s[j] == 'b')
            putchar('z');
        if (s[j]=='z')
            putchar('a');
        j++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please show me where you `putchar` anything but `'a'`, `'d'` or '`z`' and you'll get some **strong hints** towards the answer to your question.

**P.S. Most importantly, if my *rather educated* guess was correct, YOU NEED A BOOK!** You can't safely learn C without one. It's not *theoretically impossible*, but **it is practically unlikely** that you'll get it right without wasting *heaps of time* writing *really unstable code*.

I recommend K&R2E. It's not *beginner friendly* in the sense that it assumes you know some other programming concepts, but then again, C is not a *beginner friendly* language in the sense that you can't just mash your face against a keyboard and win.

If you're looking for something *beginner friendly*, choose a different language. C doesn't yet have any *beginner friendly* resources, or any reputable teachers that start from a *beginner* level, to the best of my knowledge.

If you're going to program in C, it is expected that you be able to read... books, manuals and error messages from compilers and *valgrind* all need the same kind of attention to detail that your code needs.

Anything you do manage to learn without a book, you're likely going to have to unlearn. So **stop guessing immediately, start reading immediately** and hopefully next time I hear from you it's not about something *basic* and *explained by the book*.

Comment: It may also be helpful to direct OP to the following link [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and with the **note** to talk to the duck...`:)`